# RVM unsetting PATH variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I am running the following command on my machine:

**rvm use ruby -v 2.1.1** and I get the following error afterwards:

```
Using /home/sfawebuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2 Command 'sort' is available in '/usr/bin/sort'Command 'head' is available in '/usr/bin/head'   The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.   head: command not foundsort: command not found
```

It looks like it is overwriting the PATH value and removing /usr/bin. I then source my .profile file, which contains /usr/bin in it. When I run the above command again, I get the exact same error. So somewhere within RVM, it's doing an export PATH='...' something that overwrites and somehow forgets to include the original path, which has /usr/bin. It's an annoying issue having to manually source .profile after any rvm command. I took a look at the code, but it's kinda confusing. Anyone have any experience seeing this issue and how it was resolved?

output from rvm list:

```
Command 'awk' is available in '/usr/bin/awk'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
awk: command not found
Command 'dpkg' is available in '/usr/bin/dpkg'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dpkg: command not found
Command 'tr' is available in '/usr/bin/tr'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
tr: command not found
/somepath/.rvm/scripts/functions/utility_system: line 21: awk: command not found
/somepath/.rvm/scripts/functions/utility_system: line 22: dpkg: command not found
/somepath/.rvm/scripts/functions/utility_system: line 191: tr: command not found

rvm rubies

/somepath/.rvm/scripts/list: line 245: sort: command not found

No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.
```

Comment: try:
`rvm reload` and `rvm install 2.1.1` and `rvm use 2.1.1`

Comment: That's amazing that it was that simple! Thanks Maringan! Saved me a ton of time... I like to try to figure things out on my own first, but after an unfruitful 8 or so hours, I decided it was time to seek help :-) Appreciate the prompt response.